# Are there safe alternatives to bitwise operators in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use some bitwise operators in my JS (especially left and right shift, such as bytes[i + 1] << 8). However, TypeScript generates warnings and I see the value in avoiding this to minimize the risk of serious typos.

Furthermore, regardless of linting errors, [bitwise operators are unsafe on numbers over 2^32](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND)

What is a type-safe alternative to bitwise operators such as `<<`, `>>`, `&`, and `|`?

Comment: You could disable the [no-bitwise](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-bitwise/) rule if you want to write code like that. This isn't a type safety problem, it's coming from your *linter*.

Comment: I know how to disable the linter, but like the value of this check (to avoid bad typos) outside of a very few functions where I do use bitwise operators.

Comment: Then are you really asking how to disable the rule in a specific scope, rather than (per the title and content of the question) what an alternative implementation would be? That's covered in [the docs](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/).

Comment: @RobertT Then only disable the rule for those lines but keep it on otherwise.

Comment: /* tslint:disable:no-bitwise */ and /* tslint:enable:no-bitwise */ is perfect to ignore the specific function where I'm using them, thank you all!